# C error SQL pointer

Tags: c

My function takes pointer `*d` as parameter.

I wrote that line - `EXEC SQL VAR d->x is STRING;`
Actually I want a variable  which can store the value of `d->x`.
with that variable i can manipulate some other work.

I get the following error

```
 Semantic error
 EXEC SQL VAR d->x is STRING;
```

Waiting for your suggestions.

Comment: post the code please, and tell us which database you are using.

Comment: Who gives you such error? Did you compile your source using `proc` ?

Comment: oh qrdl,
i am using make file for compilation.

Comment: `make` doesn't compile by itself - it invokes some other programs, based on dependency rules. So my question is - which program gets invoked by `make` to perform actual compilation? Or this question is no longer relevant, as you have accepted obviously incorrect answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to guess, you want to have a `char` array, or a `char` pointer with enough memory, and then put your query string in it:

```
char query[BIG_ENOUGH];
sprintf(query, "EXEC SQL VAR %s is STRING;", d->x);
```

The above assumes that your have a string in `d->x`, and that you want the string value in your SQL query.  I don't know if your SQL query is well-formed though.

If this is not what you want, you need to post more information.

Comment: Miss! `EXEC SQL VAR` is Oracle's embedded SQL statement, can be included directly into source